# Does Index Fragmentation of an Unused Table Increases?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I'm a newbie to SQL Server database, the version is SQL Server 2017. And I would like to know that, will the index fragmentation of a long-time-unused table increase from time to time?

*Long-time-unused table is meaning that the table has no activity for a long time, no insert, no update, and no delete were performed on that table.

If the answer is yes, is there any thing that causes such?

Thanks :)

Comment: *"the version is SQL Server 2017"* Then why have you tagged `sql-server-2008` and not `sql-server-2017`? :)

Comment: No. Fragmentation occurs when data is modified. Why the question though? Did you encounter a problem and thought fragmentation was the issue?

Comment: Shrinking a data file can increase fragmentation.

Comment: Nice thought @MJH. Wouldn't be surprised to hear the OP has shrunk the database; which will could cause fragmentation on more than just their "unused" table.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, you can avoid fragmentation by specifying the `TRUNCATEONLY` option.

Comment: @Larnu, that's why I said I'm a newbie to SQL Server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hi there, it is just a curious thought hahhaa

Comment: @Larnu, and thanks for the clarification too :)

Comment: @MJH, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of fragmentation - Internal (page fullness) and External (page ordering).

Shrinking a datafile can increase external fragmentation for the whole database, you can avoid it by using the `TRUNCATEONLY` option, see the following link:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4368/execute-sql-server-dbcc-shrinkfile-without-causing-index-fragmentation/